# Работа с файлами и директориями

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, файлы

Доброе время суток.
 С прошедшими и наступающими праздниками.

У меня такая проблема возникла.
Нужно чтобы название директории бралось с файла. 
 Я это делаю так

```
// Проверяем, существует ли директория, соответствующая сегодняшней дате,
// если нет - создаем, если да, продолжаем.

DecodeDate(now, Year, Month, Day);
Day1:=IntToStr(Day);
Month1:=IntToStr(Month);
if Length(Day1)=1 then insert('0',Day1,1);
if Length(Month1)=1 then insert('0',Month1,1);

FileNameWithPath:=FileListBox1.Items[n];
FileName:=ExtractFileName(FileNameWithPath);

if not DirectoryExists(DestinationDir+'\'+Day1+Month1+'-'+FileName) then
    if not CreateDir(DestinationDir+'\'+Day1+Month1+'-'+FileName) then
        raise Exception.Create('Cannot create '+DestinationDir+'\'+Day1+Month1+'-'+FileName);

If not MoveFile(PChar(FileListBox1.Items[n]), PChar(DestinationDir+'\'+Day1+Month1+FileName+'\'+FileListBox1.Items[n])) then
```

Все работает когда я не вписываю FileName - программа создает папку с датой и вложит туда файлы.

Мне нужно чтобы программа создала папку в таком формате "числом+название файла" и перемещала туда файлы.
Сейчас программа FileName создает папку "числом+название файла", но дописывает еще расширения файла.

Файл может иметь одно название, но разные расширения. И мне нужно чтобы файлы с одинаковыми названиями ложились в одну папку.

Comment: @kadekin778, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам подсказки:

```
FilenameWithoutExtension:=ChangeFileExt(Filename,'');//Имя файла без расширения
Directory:= //Директория назначения
  DestinationDir+'\'+
  FormatDateTime('ddmm',now)+'-'+FilenameWithoutExtension;
```

Comment: Всем спасибо все получилось